# Tzlofachad's reason of death?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, parashat-shelach, parsha-torah-portion, pinchas

In this weeks parasha, Pinchas, Tzlofachad's daughters go to Moshe and say about their father dying was not due to other people, rather due to himself. The gemara in [Shabbos 96b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.96b.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) notes that Rabbi Akiva says because he was the gatherer of sticks. Whereas, R' Shimon says he is part of the HaMafilim Shelach 14:4. But surely R' Shimon's opinion is saying that he was part of a people?

Comment: Whilst this may not entirely answer your question it is worth noting that the [Sifri Zuta, Bamidbar 15:32](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34332&st=&pgnum=42) notes that it can't be said the gatherer of sticks was Tzelofechad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always understood that "he died by his own sin" is opposed to "died because he question Moshe and Aharon (Korach and his group)"

Comment: not sure how this answers the question

Comment: @Russell It does. question asks "According to one opinion, Tzlofachad died while being in a group of siners, and not individually", I answer " 'died in his sin' does not mean he was not part of a group, it's just say he was not rebellious"

Comment: But wasn't the HaMafilim a rebellious act?

Comment: @Russell Act over over-zeal.

Comment: Yes I understand now

Answer (score 1):

It says "he died by his own sin." The various groups were killed in the desert by plague or fire as punishment for their collective failure -- and to teach the rest of the people a lesson -- whereas the *ma'apilim* died on the battlefield. So it was his personal choice to gun a-blazing (okay, "swords a-blazing") into heavily-fortified enemy territory, and his death was a direct, non-miraculous, consequence of that. Apparently R' Shimon feels that qualifies as "he died by his own sin."